# Copy file(s) from S3 bucket to EC2 home using cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to copy a file from S3 bucket to EC2 home directory. I wrote a script using help from this [SOF Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60552370/how-do-i-copy-data-from-aws-s3-to-ec2-in-a-cloudformation-template)

However in my case the script is getting executed without any errors but I am unable to see the file getting copied in my instance.
Can someone help me figure out what am I missing.

Cloud formation script:

```yaml
Properties:
  ImageId: !FindInMap [Region2AMI, !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'AMI']
  InstanceType: t2.micro
  SecurityGroups:
    - !Ref WebserverSecurityGroup
  Tags:
    - Key: Name
      Value: Amazon Linux w/ nginx included -2
  KeyName: !Ref KeyName
  UserData:
    'Fn::Base64': !Sub |
      #!/bin/bash -x
      yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
      sudo yum install git -y
      sudo yum update -y
      sudo yum install nginx -y
      sudo service nginx enable
      sudo service nginx start
      mkdir /home/ec2-user/s3-dist
      aws s3 cp s3://ai-dashboard-bucket/dist.zip /tmp
      unzip -d /home/ec2-user/s3-dist /tmp/dist.zip
      /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource EC2Instance --region ${AWS::Region}  --configSets InstallAndConfig
```

Edit : I checked the logs file and this is error I am getting.
I checked the logs and found the following error

> aws s3 sync s3://ai-dashboard-bucket/dist.zip /home/ec2-user fatal
> error: Unable to locate credentials

How do I pass credentials?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How do you know it is executing without errors? Are you checking `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` on the server?

Comment: I checked the logs and found the following error aws s3 sync s3://ai-dashboard-bucket/dist.zip /home/ec2-user fatal error: Unable to locate credentials

Comment: Scripts entered as user data are run as the root user, so do not use the sudo command in the script. Remember that any files you create will be owned by root.

Comment: Did you assign an IAM instance profile to the EC2 instance that has the appropriate S3 permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the IAM instance profile doesn't have the permissions to access objects in `ai-dashboard-bucket`.

Try adding an IAM Instance profile to your EC2 instance

```yaml
Resources:
  InstanceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties: 
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Policies: 
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: 's3:Get*'
                Resource: !Sub 'arn:${AWS::Partition}:s3:::ai-dashboard-bucket/*'

  InstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Roles: 
        - !Ref InstanceRole
  Ec2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: !FindInMap [Region2AMI, !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'AMI']
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      IamInstanceProfile: !GetAtt InstanceRole.Arn  # Using the role created above
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref WebserverSecurityGroup
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Amazon Linux w/ nginx included -2
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      UserData:
        'Fn::Base64': !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash -x
          yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
          sudo yum install git -y
          sudo yum update -y
          sudo yum install nginx -y
          sudo service nginx enable
          sudo service nginx start
          mkdir /home/ec2-user/s3-dist
          aws s3 cp s3://ai-dashboard-bucket/dist.zip /tmp
          unzip -d /home/ec2-user/s3-dist /tmp/dist.zip
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource EC2Instance --region ${AWS::Region}  --configSets InstallAndConfig
```

Comment: To the OP: I'd consider removing the unnecessary sudo and use sudo/su to ec2-user when manipulating folders/files under /home/ec2-user otherwise they won't be accessible to ec2-user.